# Error Handling If Closing Excel During A Loop

Tags: excel, error-handling, vbscript

I'm running a Loop (below) to write data from excel row by row.  But if excel is closed during the loop I would like an error message box stating "Script has been terminated".  Currently, if I close excel I get the Windows Script Host critical message error:  "Object Required: 'rw.Cells'

Any idea how I can prevent this Windows Script Host error from appearing and show my custom message box that the script has been canceled?  I'm using the below if statement within the loop and it's not working.

IF Statement:

```
If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
  On Error GoTo 0
  Wscript.Echo "Script Has Been Terminated"
  Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Below is the Loop:

```
Sub Main
subGetSession
subGoToScreen "DELP", "********", "0000000001"
Dim rw
Dim TITLE
    TITLE = "Script Completion Confirmation"
Set atlDirectorObject  = CreateObject("atlDirectorObject.atlDirector")
Set objExcel           = createobject("Excel.Application")
Set objExcelWb         = 
objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Scripting\0711_Settlement2.xlsx")
Set objExcelSht        = objExcelWb.Worksheets("Test")
Set oFileObject        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
rw = 2
objExcel.Visible = True
Do While objExcel.CountA(objExcelSht.Rows(rw)) > 0
    subDoWork objExcelSht.Rows(rw)
    rw = rw + 1

If (Err.Number <> 0) Then
On Error GoTo 0
Wscript.Echo "Script Has Been Terminated"
Wscript.Quit
End If
On Error GoTo 0 

Loop
Msgbox "End of Worksheet Has Been Reached" & chr(13) & "" & chr(13) & "Script 
Completed!", vbOkOnly, TITLE
End Sub
```

Edit:  So I have tried to implement what you stated in the comment.  And I must be doing something wrong. It's not working tho, what am I doing wrong?  This is what I have so far:

I'm declaring the variable globally as:

```
Public runningScript
```

Then for the beginning of the loop I am setting it to true and at the end of the loop I am setting it to false:

```
Do While objExcel.CountA(objExcelSht.Rows(rw)) > 0
runningScript  = True
    subDoWork objExcelSht.Rows(rw)
    rw = rw + 1
runningScript  = False
Loop
```

Then subDoWork executes if the variable runningScript is true:

```
Sub subDoWork(rw)
If runningScript = True Then
' all the code goes here
Else
subTerminateScript "Script Canceled"
End If
End Sub
```

Then in excel, I have the following before close event:

```
Public Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
runningScript = False
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?????

Comment: You can define Public bool that will be set to true when, the loop starts. During loop each time You will check if this public bool is true if not then You should terminate Your sub, after the loop finishes work set publi bool to false.
On the other hand add Workbook.BeforeClose Event that will check before excel close if public bool is true, if it is it means that Your loop is running, so You can display MsgBox.

Comment: I'm not really up on VBScript - can you access the workbook events and hook into the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event?

Comment: that's a great idea, I will do that.  But using the bool and the before close event won't remove the windows script host error will it?

Comment: It will not remove the window automatically, but when Your loop will see that it can not run as bool is false, then the macro will end before the workbook will be closed, e. g. in loop when You check the bool and see it is false (it means that workbook before close event changed it state from true to false during loop execution) then You can "end" the sub, e. g. 
If(testbool = False) Then 
   End
End If
Here is example of before close event - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-beforeclose-event-excel

Comment: Mikisz i tried to implement what you stated in the "Edit".  setting it to true, executing if it's true and then setting it to false when the workbook closes, but for whatever reason, when I close excel, it does not change the variable to false.  what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why I can't figure this out.  I believe I am not placing the variable to true and/or false in the correct area.  I also don't believe that excel is talking to my script, even with the before close event.  this doesn't seem that complicated, I don't know why can't figure this out.  Am I not placing my variables in the correct area of the sub?